# Retrieving facebook user's friendlist in android

Tags: android, facebook

I am designing an android app in which I have already asked the user to login through webview. This login was used in action which were also performed using webview.
Now the problem is, I need to get list of user's friends with their profile id.
So the question is, will I need to ask user again for login if I use facebook android sdk to retrieve friendlist? If yes, any third party options?

Answer (score 0):

If the user is logged in through a webview, either directed via the app or prior to opening it, you should have some sort of session token available.

This token can be used with the Facebook SDK SessionState to check if the user is authenticated. If they are authenticated, retrieving additional information (friends list, profile picture, etc.) can be done.

[Here is a tutorial for showing the friends list to an authenticated user.](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/android/scrumptious/show-friends)